# Как на jquery найти несколько элементов идущих подряд в DOM и обернуть их в контейнер?

Tags: jquery

Есть следующий код:

```
<p>
   <img src.../>
   <img src.../>
</p>
<p>
   <img src.../>
   <img src.../>
   <img src.../>
</p>
<p>
   <img src.../>
</p>
```

Как с помощью jquery обернуть в контейнер те теги img, которые идут **подряд** чтобы стало так?

```
<p>
   <span class='set'>
      <img src.../>
      <img src.../>
   </span>
</p>
<p>
   <span class='set'>
      <img src.../>
      <img src.../>
      <img src.../>
   </span>
</p>
<p>
   <img src.../>
</p>
```

Есть метод wrapAll, но я не понимаю, что ему передать

```
$("???").wrapAll("<span class='set'>");
```

Если делать wrapAll по *img+img* он обернет второй, третий и последующие, но не первый, а *p>img* перенесет все шесть img в первый p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
$('pre').text("Исходный код: " + $('div').html());

// Перебор всех тегов "p" и "обвертывание" img'ов внутри каждого "p" отдельно.
$("p").each(function(){ 
    if ($(this).children("img").length > 1) $(this).children("img").wrapAll("<span class='set'>");
});


$('pre').text($('pre').text() + "Результат: " + $('div').html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
</pre>
<div hidden>

  <p>
     <img src />
     <img src />
  </p>
  <p>
     <img src />
     <img src />
     <img src />
  </p>
  <p>
     <img src />
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Да, но в этом случае одиночный img он тоже обернет

Comment: Верно, не обратил внимания на это условие, ответ поправил.

Comment: Да, теперь то, что нужно, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(let image of document.images){
  const parent = image.parentNode;
  if(parent.classList.contains('set')) continue;
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.classList.add('set');
  parent.insertBefore(span, parent.firstChild);
  for(let child_img of parent.getElementsByTagName('img'))
      span.appendChild(child_img);
}
```

```css
p{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.set{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img{
   width: 20px; height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>
   <img src.../>
   <img src.../>
</p>
<p>
   <img src.../>
   <img src.../>
   <img src.../>
</p>
<p>
   <img src.../>
</p>
```